# Solr 5.3 update query VS Solr 3.6 ( using php curl and json)

Tags: php, json, curl, solr

Before setting up solr 3.6 on my server, I started to work on Bitnami Solr Stack 5.0.

Here is how I used to index my data :

```
    $ch = curl_init(SOLR_HOST . SOLR_CORE_PRODUCTS . "/update?wt=json&commitWithin=4000&debugQuery=true&overwrite=&true&commit=true");

    $json = array(array("Field" => "value", "Field2" => "value2"));

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/json'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $js);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
```

Now, let's focus on Solr's man

> Solr 3.1 Example

Solr 3.2 was the first version to support the array-of-JSONObject syntax, so in Solr 3.1 one needs to use duplicate names (the "add" tag) to add more than one document at once. It is legal in JSON to have duplicate names. Example:

```
curl http://localhost:8983/solr/update/json -H 'Content-type:application/json' -d '
{
 "add": {"doc": {"id" : "TestDoc1", "title" : "test1"} },
 "add": {"doc": {"id" : "TestDoc2", "title" : "another test"} }
}'
```

I throught that :

```
    $ch = curl_init(SOLR_HOST . SOLR_CORE_PRODUCTS . "/update?wt=json&commitWithin=4000&debugQuery=true&overwrite=&true&commit=true");

    $json = array("add: " => array("doc:" =>array("Field" => "value", "Field2" => "value2")));

    $js = json_encode($json);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/json'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $js);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
```

would do the job. $js has the value : 
 `{"add: ":{"doc:":{"Field":"value","Field2":"value2"}}}`

And the error is :

> message Unexpected character '{' (code 123) in prolog; expected '<' at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,1]

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using the XML update handler. Try posting your json to:

```
curl -X POST 'http://localhost:8983/solr/update/json?commit=true' -H 'Content-type:application/json; charset=UTF-8' --data @data.json
```

Look in solrconfig.xml to check the correct request handler, on Solr 3.6 you'll have an entry like this:

```
<requestHandler name="/update/csv" class="solr.CSVRequestHandler" startup="lazy"/>
```

If you check the Solr logs you should see an exception like:

```
SEVERE: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Unexpected character '{' (code 123) in prolog; expected '<'
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,1]
        at org.apache.solr.handler.XMLLoader.load(XMLLoader.java:81)
```

and here it is clear that the XML handler is being called.

It was only on versions of Solr > 4.* that the update handler can determine the data type from the stream.